# Getting size and height of binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

Currently, I'm trying to find the height and size of a binary tree, however I'm running into some issues. My code currently will not compile and I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong for the life of me.

```
template <class T>
int getHeight() const {
    int height = 0;
    Node * heightNode = new Node();
    heightNode = _root;

    height = max(right->height(), left->height()) + 1;
    return height;
}
```

my thought process is to keep traversing the left and right subtrees and adding 1 for every level of the tree we decend. However, the errors I'm getting are saying:

1. left of '->height' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
2. '_Ty std::max(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,_Pr)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
   ect.

I've tried a few things like this->right.height() ect.

Next, the size function

```
int getSize() const {
    int size;
    inorderTraverse(cout, this->Node->left); //L 
    size++;                               //V
    inorderTraverse(cout, this->Node->right);//R
    return size;
}
```

My thoughts were to use the inorder traversal that I've already written and tested to try and walk through each node, and instead of printing the vertex, add 1 to size for every vertex.

I'm getting the same errors for my getSize operation. Obviously there must be some fundamental flaw with my C++ code, but I cannot figure it out myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class BST{
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node * parent;
    };
    private:
    Node * root;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is `Node` and what is `_root`?

Comment: Did you mean `template <class T>
int Node<T>::getHeight() const` ? I suspect that you define free function whereas you want class methods.

Comment: number = max(right->height(), left->height()) + 1;, yet you return height, which is set to 0 and doesn't change. Furthermore, your code here is out of context - post your binary tree implementation etc.

Comment: A Node is a vertex of my binary search tree. Think of it as a linked list. _root is the base of that binary search tree.

Comment: @Vorren sorry about that, it's actually correct in my code. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is best here to get rid of the manual memory management and use `std::unique_ptr` for the left and right child nodes. These should be correctly initialized to `nullptr`. The non-owning parent node pointer can remain a raw pointer, but be careful that you do not `delete` its content.

```
class BST
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        T data;
        Node* parent;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
    };
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
};
```

Then, a recursive height definition in class `Node` might look like this:

```
int height()
{
    //I'm assuming both nodes are either set or unset
    if(left == nullptr && right == nullptr) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::max(left->height(), right->height()) + 1;
    }
}
```

The above function gives the root node -- if it is the only avilable node -- a depth of zero. As written, I assume that either both nodes are set or unset, i.e. the case that only the left or only the right node is set does not occur (strictly, one could then omit one check for `nullptr` for both child nodes). If this doesn't hold, the code can be easily adjusted.

Further, you could also abbreviate the check by using the conversion-to-bool property of `unique_ptr`

```
if(left && right) 
{
    //...
}
```

which looks a bit nicer,

Comment: still doesn't work. For some reason it does not actually access the left and right node.

Comment: it works and gives at least what I would expect, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b64b25a5842ee0).